# When one can say $f(a)\leq (1-\delta) f(b) \Rightarrow a\leq (1-\epsilon) b $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality, maxima-minima

Fix $a, b \in (0, \infty)$ such that $a<b$. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be twice differentiable function. Assume that $f$ is nonnegative and strictly increasing on $(a,b)$ and $f'(x)=0 $ if and only if $f(b)=0.$ And $f''(b)\neq 0,$ $f(a)\leq (1-\delta) f(b)$  for a fix $\delta >0.$ Also $f(0)=0.$

> My Question: Can we expect to find  $\epsilon >0$(depending on $\delta$ and $C$) such that $a\leq  (1-\epsilon) b$?

**Edit**: Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} x- \frac{C}{6}x^{3}$ (for some fix constnat $C>0$)
Then what can we say?

Comment: In the end you write $(1-\epsilon)f(b)$; I assume you mean $(1-\epsilon)b$ as in the title?

Comment: As written, it seems that the answer is obviously no, but I can't tell whether the meaning of the question has been obscured by typos.

Comment: HvE: Tahnks: It was typo

Answer (score 3):

Certainly not. If $f$ has the property for some $a,b$, then for any $c>0$, the function $x\mapsto f(x-c)$ has the property for $a+c,b+c$. And $\frac{a+c}{b+c}\to 1$ as $c\to\infty$.

*Edit:* I just noticed that I ignored the condition $f(0)=0$, which seems to destroy this simple form of translation. But that is easily mended by working piece-wise.

Comment: @HVE:Is this true for particular function:  $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} x- \frac{C}{6}x^{3}$ (for some fix constnat $C>0$) and assume it satisfies the above property? Thanks: